# Text value of Text Field is Empty Swift

Tags: uitextfield, swift

I got a textfield where you need to enter your name in.
But when i try to store the value of the textfield in my array, the value of the text field is always empty.

I declared these `IBOutlets`

```
@IBOutlet var input: UITextField
@IBOutlet var error: UILabel
```

error is a label where I store a error message.

My `IBAction` when the button is clicked:

```
    @IBAction func btnSave() {
        println("Clicked on Save")
        println("\(input.text)")
        if input.text.isEmpty {
           error.text = "Enter a name"
        } else {
           clNaam.addName(input.text)
           self.view.endEditing(true)
           error.text = ""
        }
    }
```

Everything is hooked up correctly. 
This is my class for adding a name.

```
var clNaam: addNaam = addNaam()

struct naam {
   var naam = "Nil"
}

class addNaam: NSObject {
    var aNaam = naam[]()

    func addName(name: String) {
        aNaam.append(naam(naam: name))
    }
 }
```

There probably is a problem in my code but I can't find it, I searched on the web and the  apple developer site but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you just tried to simply log `input.text`?

Comment: Yes I actually did just with println

Comment: Try printing it inside `addNaam` just to verify that it is being called and with the correct text. Also, is the array just empty when after you call `addNaam`?

Comment: Bas,

I've just created a project with your code, and the println gives the actual textfield value without problem. I also get inside the else.

Comment: hmm weird, thanks for trying that, i'm also gonna create a new project and see if that also fixes the problem for me:)

Comment: Have you tried unwrapping the text `input.text!`

Comment: Yes I also tried unwrapping it, I still can't figure out what's going wrong!